# Colocar los 'id' de mis input's en formData para la subida de imagen en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hola necesito saber como puedo agregar a `formData` los **id** "no los name" de mis inputs de mi div ya que solo acabo de encontra para uno que es el `file` pero yo necesito pasarle los demas `inputs`, que para ser exactos ya tengo capturas y previamnete guardados en una variable llamado `dataString`

El problema que tengo esque si le paso los dos parametros como
`data: {formData: formData, dataString: dataString},` 
Me dice que no tengo ningun archivo seleccionado, pero si solo le paso el `data: {formData: formData}` ahi sime sube la imagen pero no los datos en la `BD`:

```
function guardar_compra() {

    var numero_compra = $('#numero_compra').val();
    var id_proveedor = $('#id_proveedor').val();
    var monto_total = $('#monto_total').val();
    var fecha_compra = $('#fecha_compra').val();
//    var formData = new FormData($("#form-create-empleado")[0]);

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        var dataString = 'numero_compra=' + numero_compra
                + '&id_proveedor=' + id_proveedor
                + '&monto_total=' + monto_total
                + '&fecha_compra=' + fecha_compra;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/guardar_compra',
            data: {formData: formData, dataString: dataString},
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                var resultado = $.trim(result);
                if (resultado == "exito") {
                    $("#modal_form_producto").modal('hide');
                    $('#notificacion').modal('show');
                    $('#msg_respuesta').html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6>Producto Guardado</FONT>");
                    limpiar();
                    reload_tabla_pagos();
                } else {
                    alert("Error!" + result);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
        });
}



public function guardar_compra() {
        $numero_compra = $this->input->post('numero_compra');
        $id_proveedor = $this->input->post('id_proveedor');
        $monto_total = $this->input->post('monto_total');
        $fecha_compra = $this->input->post('fecha_compra');
        $config = [
            "upload_path" => "./dist/img/compras",
            'allowed_types' => "png|jpg"
        ];

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
            $datos = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            if ($this->compras->guardar_compra($numero_compra, $id_proveedor, $monto_total, $fecha_compra, $datos) == true)
                echo "exito";
            else
                echo "error";
        }
        else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form_compra"
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3 id="msg_cabecera" class="modal-title text-center"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Nº de Recibo</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input id="numero_compra"
                                                   placeholder="Ingrese numero de recibo" required
                                                   class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Proveedor</label>
                                        <input id="id_proveedor" type="hidden">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <select class="form-control select2" id="nombre_proveedor"
                                                    style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Monto Total</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input id="monto_total"
                                                   placeholder="Ingrese monto Total" required
                                                   class="form-control" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Fecha</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input id="fecha_compra"
                                                   placeholder="01/01/2017" required readonly=""
                                                   class="form-control datepicker" type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                    <label align="center" class="control-label col-md-12">Imagen</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div id="form_derivacion" class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                                <input id="file" name="file" type="file" data-show-upload="false" class="file"  required="true" accept="image/*">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <button type="button" id="boton_multiuso"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;GUARDAR</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>&nbsp;CANCELAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, compartí el código del form y de guardar_compra por favor. Probablemente se solucione con formData.append('numero_compra', numero_compra);

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con tus sugerencias gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué quieres enviar la instancia de `FormData` dentro de un objeto y encima, un string conteniendo varios datos? Un objeto `FormData`, **como su nombre lo indica** almacena datos de un formulario, incluído archivos.

Todo lo que debes hacer es serializar tu formulario:

```
const form = document.getElementById('tuform');
const formData = new FormData(form);
```

Y luego enviar el objeto `data` por ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + 'Compras/guardar_compra',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var resultado = $.trim(result);
            if (resultado == 1) {
                $("#modal_form_producto").modal('hide');
                $('#notificacion').modal('show');
                $('#msg_respuesta').html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6>Producto Guardado</FONT>");
                limpiar();
                reload_tabla_pagos();
            } else {
                alert("Error!" + result);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

**PD:** No olvides poner los atributos `name` a tus controles porque serán usados por `FormData` como claves.

---

### Actualización

> Debido a que en principio pones un formulario y luego dices que es con div (siempre pon lo que usas), actualizo la respuesta modificando algunas partes.

Lo único que cambia es que, en lugar de recibir el formulario por parámetro en el constructor de `FormData` -el cual automáticamente pone todos los controles del mismo en la instancia-, debes agregar manualmente los datos que desees:

```
var numero_compra = $('#numero_compra').val();
var id_proveedor = $('#id_proveedor').val();
var monto_total = $('#monto_total').val();
var fecha_compra = $('#fecha_compra').val();
var imagen = $('#file')[0].files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("numcompra", numero_compra);
formData.append("proveedor", id_proveedor);
formData.append("monto", monto_total);
formData.append("fecha", fecha_compra);
formData.append("imagen", imagen);

// enviar por ajax como se indica más arriba
```

Comment: El form lo utilze proque lo vi en un ejemplo en si es un div, en conclusion solo es con name lo que pasa esque tengo una validacion que por motivo de que no vean mucho codigo lo borre

Comment: Si es con un div, cosa que en principio no tiene mucha utilidad, deberías de agregar manualmente los valores al FormData, tanto la imagen como los valores de los controles. Por ejemplo: `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append("imagen", fileInput.files[0]); formData.append("monto", Number(montoInput.value));`, etc. Al final, envías ese FormData por ajax. **No metas** el FormData dentro de un objeto: `data: { data: formData }`, envíalo directamente como valor: `data: formData`.

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta, acabo de borrar el form

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores Ahí la he editado. La próxima vez pon lo que usas para que se te dé una respuesta basada en eso. Como consejo, usa un formulario para que te ahorres todo ello (puedes tener validaciones y usar un formulario sin problema).

Comment: Lo siento esque estaba mirando ejemplos con form y de mono lo puse pero no me fije a la hora de copiar el codigo, de todas formas gracias por tu respuesta, por ende pido un voto a favor :P

Comment: jaja ya está hecho :)

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo en tu form solo tienes agregado el input file

```
<form id="form-create-empleado">
   <label align="center" class="control-label col-md-12">Imagen</label>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div id="form_derivacion" class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <input id="file" name="file" type="file" data-show-upload="false" class="file"  required="true" accept="image/*">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Coloca los demas campos dentro del form, y para enviar los datos usas:

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
```

con eso te evitas estar haciendo

```
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
```

con cada dato del formulario.

Para recibir los datos es necesario que los inputs tengan el atributo name.

Comment: El form lo utilze proque lo vi en un ejemplo en si es un div, en conclusion solo es con name lo que pasa esque tengo una validacion que por motivo de que no vean mucho codigo lo borre

Comment: Pero usa el form, así te evitas hacer el envió de cada uno de tus inputs. SI quieres hacer validaciones, igual puedes usar los datos del form, y antes de hacer el envio por ajax validas tus datos.